# How to change texts colors in my case

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have bunch of links and I need to change the texts color to red after user clicks them

I have something like:

```
<li class="test" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a href="" ng-click="clickMe()" class="test-li">
    {{item.name}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Currently the style is like

```
.test-li {
  color: black;
}
```

I want my texts to turn red after user clicks them.

So I do:

```
.test-li:visited {
    color:red;
}
```

It works when I click the item, but the color changes back to black after I click another item. I feel like this can be archive simply in CSS without setting ng-class. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: test-li is already a class refer to the a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any destination url given in your links, so there really isn't a way for the browser to know which links have been visited. I think if you were to add a simple #test, #test1, #test2, etc to your href attribute in your links, you would find that your CSS does work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Since your link doesn't actually go anywhere, you'd be better off adding a 'visited' class to your `<a>` element when clicked, via JS.

jQuery exmample:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('visited');
  // or you could use $(this).toggleClass('visited'); depending on what you want to achieve.
});
```